# Labels are not shown correctly in WPF 2010

Tags: xaml

I have a TabControl which has four labels. Its xaml is:

```
![enter image description here][1]<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="282" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabControl1"      
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503">
        <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="101*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="367"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="125*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Library:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,15,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49" />
                <Label  Content="Museum:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="303,13,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" Grid.Row="1" />
                <Label Content="Cinema:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,11,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Grid.Row="2" />
                <Label Content="Embankment:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="281,30,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Grid.Row="3" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

When a program is run then some letters, signs are disappeared and I cannot understand the reason why. For example, in this screen shot it can be seen that colon of word “Cinema” is not drawn.
I made a grid, however, it does not help. What should I do to make my program work? It happens very often. I want all my labels to show correctly.

It can be seen that a **colon** of a word “Cinema” is not drawn.

[image: two muppets]

Comment: try removing the "Width" of the labels and allow the content to size the control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the "Width" of the labels and allow the content to size the control

```
<Grid>
        <TabControl Height="282" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabControl1"      
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503">
            <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="101*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="367"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="125*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="Library:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,15,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                    <Label  Content="Museum:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="303,13,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Label Content="Cinema:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,11,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="2" />
                    <Label Content="Embankment:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="281,30,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="3" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank a lot:).
I cleared everywhere "Width"  and used "HorizontalAlignment=Right". And All becomes o'kay.